# How to flag a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I recently flagged a few porn uploads and since those videos violated the rules they've been removed. How can I flag a YouTube playlist instead of having to click on each video?

Comment: See [Flagging content - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802027?hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

On a playlist page, you can click on the vertical three dots button (More) to flag the playlist. Note that this only flags the playlist itself, not the videos within the playlist.

[image: IMG:]

If you often flag videos, you may want to apply to the heroes program as it offers scaled flagging tools: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7124236?hl=en